# Calling a method from a separate class(Expected class or package)

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to access the "ResumeScreen" method from a class named "draw".

I'm receiving an exception that states `Expected class or package` in my use of "play"(An instance of "draw") in the unPause method. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I've commented where the issue is occurring.

```
public class paused extends JPanel {

    JPanel pause = new JPanel();
    public JButton resume;
    public JButton settings;
    public JButton main;
    draw play = new draw();

    public paused() {

        // Buttons declared
        resume = new JButton("Resume");
        settings = new JButton("Settings");
        main = new JButton("Main Menu");

        // Sets dimensions and location of buttons
        pause.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pause, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        pause.add(resume);
        pause.add(settings);
        pause.add(main);
        resume.addActionListener(new unPause());

        pause.revalidate();
        pause.repaint();
        pause.setVisible(true);
        this.add(pause);
    }

    private class unPause implements ActionListener {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            remove(pause);
            play.ResumeScreen(); //This is where the issue occurs
            revalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it means there is no class draw in that same package. you'll need to import it

Comment: How would I import it? At the top with all of my other imports? I thought creating an instance such as "play" covered that. Thanks!

Comment: nope. that just instantiates, but if the class isn't in the same package/path, it's a compile time error

Comment: Awesome thank you, any idea how I would import/add draw to the package/path? I can't seem to find any info on that

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the right components for ActionListener to work? ( import java.awt.event.*; )

Create your instance of the draw() class in a constructor in your unPause class and try compiling then.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I am, sorry I forgot to include imports. Heres a list: import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

Comment: Not yet unfortunately, still having the error. I was looking into how I could import the class at the top with all of the other import statements but I couldn't figure that out either

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

Import package_name.class_name

And it should help your program with the package/class path resolve